# Example of a non-Borel set on Euclidean space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Can someone give an example of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n >1$, that is not a Borel set?

Comment: If you know a non Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$, say $X$, then $X\times\{0\}^{n-1}$ is a non Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: It's probably enough to take an example in $\mathbb{R}$ and just take $n$ products of it with it self.

Comment: @AlexL: Is there a non-degenerate example?

Comment: @DanRust: Is the proof straightforward?

Comment: I don't know, give it a go yourself :). It's the first non-trivial example that one would naturally try. Even if your attempt fails, it should inform your next attempt.

Comment: How explicit do you want your example? There are $|\mathbb{R}|$ Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, while there are $2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$ subsets total. So, most of them are not Borel

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf: I didn’t get any responses or directions to my earlier question. So was trying to figure out. I think you partially answered it. I just wanted to know if it’s not just degenerate and pathological cases.            https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2978391/420602

Comment: I couldn't check the link (it seems to have been deleted). Definitely there are non degenerate examples, since if $X$ is not Borel, its complement neither is (assuming I'm taking the right meaning of degeneracy); also, the same cardinality argument applies to null sets. Finally there are non pathological examples (I.e. the projection of a $G_\delta$ in a higher dimensional Euclidean space).